# Scheme : precision of decimal numbers

Tags: scheme, decimal, precision

How can I convert `42.0` to `42.00` in Scheme?
For Example (In Scheme):
When I do `(/ 20.00 2)`, I get `10.0`. I want `10.00` as the result of above instead of `10.0`

Comment: I don't get 10.0; I get 1e1.  My point being it is all about the external representation

Answer (score 7):

Óscar's solution works well, but an even easier solution is to use [SRFI-48](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-48/srfi-48.html), which provides additional format directives.

`(display (format "~0,2F" (/ 20.00 2)))`

Answer (score 5):

The objects represented by `10.0` and `10.00` are the same.  There is no such thing as a fixed-precision decimal number in R5RS Scheme.  What do you need the fixed precision for?  If it is relevant for output, you need to do formatted printing of some sort.  Check your Scheme implementation's documentation about a `printf` or `format` function.  If, on the other hand, you actually need decimal arithmetic, you will need to either use exact ratios and round explicitly according to the rules you want to use, or use integers and treat them as units of size 1/100.

Answer (score 4):

The numbers `10.0` and `10.00` are exactly the same. Maybe you want to format your output to a string with a fixed number of decimals to the right of the dot? try this:

```
(define (right-pad number len)
  (let* ((nstr (number->string number))
         (diff (- len (string-length nstr)))
         (pads (if (> diff 0) (make-string diff #\0) "")))
    (string-append nstr pads)))
```

Use it like this:

```
(display (right-pad (/ 20.00 2) 5))
> 10.00
```

Notice that the `len` parameter indicates the total amount of chars desired in the resulting string, *including* the dot. This solution has the advantage of being independent from external libraries.

Answer (score 1):

If you use racket, I think that could help.

[https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28lib.*racket%2Fformat..rkt%29.*~7er%29%29](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fformat..rkt%29._~7er%29%29)

> (~r pi #:precision 4)
>
> "3.1416"