# Don't know how to round a number in racket

Tags: scheme, racket, rounding, wescheme

I'm trying to solve a problem in racket that I need to get a student's grade and put it inside a star. But if the grade has more than one decimal case I need to round it to show only 1. Ex: If the grade is 8.67 it should show 8.7. But I can't figure how to do it.
I tried using:

```
(round 8.67)
```

But it goes to closest integer. How can I round to only one decimal?

Comment: What have you tried? You could check for each decimal case, and round to that case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scheme : precision of decimal numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10064881/scheme-precision-of-decimal-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

What would

```
(round (* 10 8.67))
```

return?

What would

```
(/ 10 (round (* 10 8.67)))
```

return? (or should the ratio be flipped?)

Can you go from here and ***generalize*** it to get a working function, by replacing the specific values with  symbolic ones, and specifying them as the function's parameters?

```
(define (nround ten eightSixtySeven)
  ......
  )
```

Or remove the `ten` parameter if you want to use the hard-coded value of 10 instead:

```
(define (round1 eightSixtySeven)
  ...... 10 .....
  )

(define (round2 eightSixtySeven)
  ...... 100 .....
  )
```

etc.